# Seeking a specific book with graphs of interesting functions, but can't remember the name

Tags: asymptotics, graphing-functions, education, book-recommendation, visualization

I am looking for a specific book that was recommended on youtube in either a Numberphile or Matt Parker video. it was a visual dictionary of pictures of interesting plots of math functions. the cover was blue and black. I think the name of the book was similar to "A List of Interesting Functions and their Graphs" IIRC. What is the name or ISBN of the book?

EDIT: I already have the NIST book. The book I am looking for would likely be in the category of recreational mathematics or mathematics as art. The video was definitely more than 6 months ago. maybe even a year ago. it was a new video at that time.

Comment: Not the exact book, but the NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions has a litany of graphs of special functions.

Comment: Was the video recent?

Comment: Or maybe Jahnke and Emde's _Tables of functions with formulas and curves_? (See https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2014/12/15/jahnke-and-emde-revisited/ )

Comment: similar but what I am looking for was printed after the year 2000. the cover of the book is blue and black.

Comment: Lockwood : The Book of Curves : Link https://www.amazon.co.uk/Book-Curves-H-Lockwood/dp/0521044448 or, if you've got £210 to spend Handbook and Atlas of Curves Link : https://wordery.com/handbook-and-atlas-of-curves-eugene-v-shikin-9780849389634

Comment: It could be "An Atlas of Functions with Equator, the Atlas Function Calculator" by Oldham and Spanier (c)2009.

Comment: The Handbook and Atlas of curves is $55 in Kindle form.

Answer (score 2):

I am not %100 sure but I think I found the book. I still can't find the video where Matt Parker suggested it.

**Curves for the Mathematically Curious: An Anthology of the Unpredictable, Historical, Beautiful, and Romantic**

ISBN-10 : 0691180059

ISBN-13 : 978-0691180052

[https://www.amazon.com/Curves-Mathematically-Curious-Unpredictable-Historical/dp/0691180059/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691180059)

Comment: That's a neat book. Thanks. It's available in both hardcover and Kindle.